# fseek go back to the end of file when writing a value

Tags: c++, c, fseek

I am trying to override 4 bytes at position 4 in a file, but fseek seems not to be working.

My code:

```
int r = fseek(cacheStream, 4, SEEK_SET);
std::cout << "fseek returns " << r << std::endl;
std::cout << "ftell " << ftell(cacheStream) << std::endl;
r = fwrite(&chunckSize, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, cacheStream);
std::cout << "fwrite returns " << r << std::endl;
std::cout << "ftell " << ftell(cacheStream) << std::endl;
```

cacheStream was open with "ab". The output is:

```
fseek returns 0
ftell 4
fwrite returns 1
ftell 2822716
```

The value was not overriden, but instead it was written at the end of file. What could cause that weird behaviour with fseek?

Comment: Reading manuals seems impossible.

Comment: @alk The man page for fseek did not mention that the file could not be open with "a".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `"ab"` mode means that every write will be appended to the file, regardless of position before the write.

If you don't want that, don't use the `"a"` flag.

*Added later*:

If you're opening an existing file for update, then `"r+b"` opens the file for reading and writing; `"w+b"` truncates the file when it is opened, but allows you to read what you've written.

The C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 — not the current standard, but that will be very similar) says:

> §7.19.5.3 The `fopen` function
>
> - `r` — open text file for reading
> - `w` — truncate to zero length or create text file for writing
> - `a` — append; open or create text file for writing at end-of-file
> - `rb` — open binary file for reading
> - `wb` — truncate to zero length or create binary file for writing
> - `ab` — append; open or create binary file for writing at end-of-file
> - `r+` — open text file for update (reading and writing)
> - `w+` — truncate to zero length or create text file for update
> - `a+` — append; open or create text file for update, writing at end-of-file
> - `r+b` *or* `rb+` — open binary file for update (reading and writing)
> - `w+b` *or* `wb+` — truncate to zero length or create binary file for update
> - `a+b` *or* `ab+` — append; open or create binary file for update, writing at end-of-file

Comment: @fbafelipe : Won't using "rb+/wb+", will do the trick for this case ? I am new to C, that's the best guess I can make :-)

Comment: @fbafelipe, why not using "wb" mode for writing?

Comment: @Subhajit: "wb" won't let you update existing information -- it will destroy all existing content when you open the file.

Answer (score 5):

Opening in "ab" mode will result you in adding bytes at the end of the file, you need to use "wb" mode instead to overwrite the bytes.

Comment: I don't want to erase the contents the file already have, like "wb" does.

Comment: @fbafelipe what if I want to create the file if it's not existed ?

Comment: @fbafelipe Yeah, But I meant if I don't want to erase the already existed contents, also in the same time want to modify the previous content... The "r+b" did exactly what I want, but it fail when the file isn't existed, anyway I managed to check the file existence manually and create empty one if needed.