# C - How to search a file and overwrite a portion of it

Tags: c, fopen

I'm working on a program that searches a file for a specific string that was within a struct when it was written to the file. If I find a match within that file, I need to overwrite a portion of that struct. Searching the file for the match is super easy, but I am struggling with overwriting that struct. Below is my code searching the file and *attempting* to overwrite that data.

```
dfp = fopen(archName, "ab");
    if(dfp == NULL) {
        printf("An error has occurred... %s could not be opened.\n", archName);
        return 0;
    } /* End if */

    /* Read first header file */
    fread(&getHeader, sizeof(getHeader), 1, dfp);

/* Check for match */
    if(strcmp(fName[0], getHeader.file_name) == 0) {
        getHeader.deleted = (char)49;
        fwrite(&getHeader, sizeof(getHeader), 1, dfp);
```

Note that getHeader is a struct. There are multiple structs that can be stored anywhere in my file. I need to search each header for a specific string (easy). When a match is found, that struct must be overwritten.

What kind of a process would be recommended for accomplishing such a task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a loop to read the records into a record structure, one at a time.  After each read, you can compare the record just read with the desired record, reading the next record if it is not the one you need.

You've just found the record you wanted, but you've also just read beyond the record; you have to seek back to overwrite the record.  You also have to seek between read and write or vice versa, every time, because the C standard says the behaviour is undefined if you don't.  That means a seek before the write, and another seek before going back for the next record.

Since you've opened the file in `"ab"` mode, any seeking is immaterial since all writes will be appended at the end.  You probably want `"r+b"` as the mode to `fopen()`.

See [`fseek()` goes back to the end of file when writing a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095212/fseek-go-back-to-the-end-of-file-when-writing-a-value/15095272#15095272) for a recent discussion of the same general issues.

Comment: I've actually tried using all of the options available for fopen, but to no avail... When I use "r+b" as my mode and attempt to overwrite a given struct, I end up creating a new struct directly following the struct I wish to overwrite... Is this where fseek would come into play? Do I need to set the pointer back to the beginning of the struct that I wish to overwrite?

Comment: Ahh... just realized that I had a typo in my fseek call. Thanks for the information!